# Keras model Accuracy not increasing on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Working on IMDB Dataset Google Colab, the model accuracy refuses to go above 50%.
The dataset has already been tokenized and cleaned before this.
Any suggestions on how the accuracy can be improved are welcome.

```
le=LabelEncoder()
df['sentiment']= le.fit_transform(df['sentiment'])
labels=to_categorical(df['sentiment'],num_classes=2) # this is output

max_len = 400
embeddings=256
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['review'])
sequences_padded=pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_len,padding='post',truncating='post')

num words = 10000
embeddings = 256
max_len=400

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(sequences_padded,labels,test_size=0.20,random_state=42)

model= keras.Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_words,embeddings,input_length=max_len))
model.add(Conv1D(256,10,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=3, batch_size=128, verbose=1)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )

Epoch 1/3
310/310 [==============================] - 157s 398ms/step - loss: 35.7756 - accuracy: 0.5007
Epoch 2/3
310/310 [==============================] - 123s 395ms/step - loss: 1.0212 - accuracy: 0.5003
Epoch 3/3
310/310 [==============================] - 123s 397ms/step - loss: 1.0211 - accuracy: 0.5015
```

**Update:**
Model accuracy started improving when I changed from post to pre padding. Any leads on why this happens would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You use `binary_crossentropy + softmax` instead of `categorical_crossentropy + softmax`.

Change to:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. CHanging loss didn't help improve the accuracy. However when I changed padding from post to pre; the accuracy started climbing again. Any idea why this might happen?